# looping everything in array to compare with each cell

Tags: vba, excel

how can i let my my cell be assessed by all the values in the array before moving on to the next cell

sample values inside the array
  N/A

```
R008-0097X
R005-0077X
R002-1703X
R003-0301X
R019-1439U

  For Each cel In SrchRnga  ' this entire statement does not replace anything

            If InStr(1, cel.Value, BOM(b )) > 0 Then
                cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = SAP(b)
                cel.Offset(0 + 9, 1).Value = UF(b)
                b = b + 1
            End If
Next cel
```

currently it is just **reading it once** and moving on.

```
for b =1 to 9  ' it starts replacing after i added this code
        For Each cel In SrchRnga

                    If InStr(1, cel.Value, BOM(b )) > 0 Then
                        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = SAP(b)
                        cel.Offset(0 + 9, 1).Value = UF(b)

                    End If
        Next cel
next b
```

i tried putting a for loop outside thinking that it will read the cell 8 times but this replaces all my values that isn't in the array to `""`

what i want to know is:
**how to loop the array for each cell without replacing the values that does not exist in the array.**

Comment: Where is it replacing values? you only do something when it matches.

Comment: What are the contents of SAP and UF?

Comment: i editted my question. I am not sure why adding a 'for loop' will replace all my values to ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the iterator inside the For Each loop

```
For Each cel In SrchRnga
    For b = 1 to 9        
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, BOM(b )) > 0 Then
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = SAP(b)
            cel.Offset(0 + 9, 1).Value = UF(b)
        End If
    next b
Next cel
```